# SQL Having 2 Cases In A Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have written the following query

[image]

Which results in:

[image]

Instead of joining on user_tags in lines 37 and 39, I would actually like to make a case that split up each "cohort" into a second tier cohort.

The second tier cohort would be one of two things:

If tags.name = 'sentPhone' and tags1.name = 'sentForm' then it returns 'phone_shipped', otherwise it returns 'in_person'

Would this be possible? I'd expect the end result to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I miss something, but it seems simple, you alredy did it actually.
Try add this

```
(CASE WHEN tags.name = 'sentPhone' AND tags1.name = 'sentForm' 
THEN'phone_shipped'
ELSE 'in_person') as cohort2,
```

after line 32

and on line 49 add

```
GROUP BY tags.name
```

It's not like your example because you have not duplicate the line but you really need to have these 2 line duplicated except for cohort2 that is a conditional.

Sorry if I miss something in your question.

Luca

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i get the error ERROR:  column "tags.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 21:     (CASE WHEN tags.name = 'sentPhone' AND tags1.name = 'sen...

Comment: ok and so add GROUP BY tags.name in line 49 as I add to answer.